# Is a LSTM with Argument units=N equivalent to N parallel LSTMs with units=1?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, parameters, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

Im currently starting with neural networks and especially LSTMs for timeseries Models.

I read a paper ([convex based LSTM](https://cpb-us-w2.wpmucdn.com/campuspress.yale.edu/dist/7/677/files/2016/09/paper_LSTM_2017ACC-1sz2yir.pdf)) where someone uses parallel LSTMs and combines their outputs afterwards. Now I was wondering how to implement this type of network. I understand, that the parameter "units" in the LSTM constructor in Keras is the size of the output because of the elementwise multiplication at the end. However I am not sure if a Keras-LSTM-Layer with N units is the same as a Layer with N LSTMs, each having 1 unit.

In other words: imagine two LSTMs (one with N units, one with 1 unit), which get the same input and produce output1 (length N) and output2 (length 1). Will one LSTM with units=N+1 and the same input produce the output y=[y_1, y_2] if the weights are assigned accordingly?

If that's not the case, how can you use multiple LSTMs in one layer with Keras using a Sequential model? Is it only possible with the functional API?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this paper, essentially he's combining outputs of k layers of LSTMs, each of which comes with n_k cells.
To replicate this is keras, write k layers of lstms and n_k units in each layer.
A layer of LSTM with only one unit is of no use as the memory propagates across the cells of LSTMs for sequential input. A one unit LSTM only processes one input value leaving other values as is.
So, to answer your question, no. Both are not the same. In fact N layers with 1 units is as good as one cell on the first input for all the inputs.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It makes sense that the two versions are not the same. But if I add k layers of LSTMs with model.add(LSTM(..)) they will be in series. Am I right that I have to use functional API to replicate his model?

Comment: Functional APIs are a great way to cut-short unnecessary replication of architecture and retraining to find the same weights. I didn't read the paper completely but from architecture point of view it seems that you can get it done using functional APIs in Keras to call models over your output for n number of iterations.
I'd suggest you to ask a separate question for implementation suggestions with or without functional APIs to get suggestions from other people as well. :)